# Como Fazer dois ou mais Select categorizados na mesma consulta

Tags: mysql, select

Preciso pegar todas as palavras com 'A' e jogar em 'PalavrasComA' e todas com 'B' e jogar PalavrasComB, e pode ter C, D E... O mais perto até agora foi isso, porem funcioana só com a primeira.

```
SELECT
    w1.wd as PalavrasComA,
    w2.wd as PalavrasComB
From ptbr as w1, ptbr as w2 

where left (w1.wd, 1) = 'a'

and left (w2.wd, 1) = 'b';
```

Comment: Vai ser variável ou você sabe todas as combinações?

Comment: Vai ser variável, pois eu vou digitar palavras num campo de busca e vai retornar pelo numero de palavras que começa com cada letra.

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser trazer todas em uma mesma `query` fixa pode fazer como no exemplo:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN left(w.wd, 1) = 'a' THEN 1 END) AS a,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN left(w.wd, 1) = 'b' THEN 1 END) AS b,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN left(w.wd, 1) = 'c' THEN 1 END) AS c
  FROM ptbr w
```

Se quiser retornar as palavras:

```
SELECT left(w.wd, 1) AS letra,
       GROUP_CONCAT(w.wd SEPARATOR ',') AS palavras,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN left(w.wd, 1) = 'c' THEN 1 END) AS c
  FROM ptbr w
 GROUP BY left(w.wd, 1)
```

Se quiser separar por colunas:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(IF(left(w.wd, 1) = 'a', w.wd ,'') SEPARATOR ', ') AS palavrasComA,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(left(w.wd, 1) = 'b', w.wd ,'') SEPARATOR ', ') AS palavrasComB,
       GROUP_CONCAT(IF(left(w.wd, 1) = 'c', w.wd ,'') SEPARATOR ', ') AS palavrasComC
  FROM ptbr w
```

Ou se quiser apenas a primeira palavra:

```
SELECT MIN(IF(left(w.wd, 1) = 'a', w.wd, NULL)) AS palavrasComA,
       MIN(IF(left(w.wd, 1) = 'b', w.wd, NULL)) AS palavrasComB,
       MIN(IF(left(w.wd, 1) = 'c', w.wd, NULL)) AS palavrasComC,
  FROM ptbr w
```

Comment: Neste caso aqui só retornou o numero, e não as palavras.

Comment: @MarcusViniciusTavares adicionei uma segunda opção, verifique por favor

Comment: Todas as palavras com a letra 'a' na Coluna 'pA',

Comment: Todas as palavras com a letra 'b' na Coluna 'pB',

Comment: Todas as palavras estão na mesma tabela que é um dicinonario

Comment: @MarcusViniciusTavares verifique a terceira opção

Comment: A terceira é quase perfeita para meu caso. Pórem gostaria de uma palavra por linha em cada coluna.