# Fazer dois ou mais Select com Aliases na consulta para gerar um array separado

Tags: mysql, select, alias

Eu tenho uma tabela unica de apenas uma coluna com todas as palavras em português.
Quero fazer um Select duplo ou triplo e recuperar em cada consulta todas as palavras com 'A' no alias PalavrasComA, e todas com 'B' no Alias PalavrasComB.

Quando eu recuper no PHP está vindo assim

```
[ComecaComA] => agua
[ComecaComB] => 
[ComecaComA] => agora
[ComecaComB] =>
```

e só quando começa as com 'B' vem

```
[ComecaComA] => 
[ComecaComB] => bola
[ComecaComA] => 
[ComecaComB] => bolado
```

quero pegar todas com 'A' primeiro no array 0 por exemplo
e depois todas com 'B' no array 1.

```
"select if( w.word like 'a%', w.word, '') as ComecaComA,
       if(w.word like 'b%', w.word, '') as ComecaComB

from teste as w limit 0,400000"
```

Estou criando um corretor de palavras, e ele funciona palavra por palavra com a query a seguir:

```
$wd = substr($palavra,0,1);

$palavras = "select `wd` from ptbr where left (`wd`, 1) = '$wd'";
```

Ele me retorna todas a palavras que começam com a letra da palavra e eu faço comparação via php. Até ai da tudo certo.
Mas quero que quando tiver mais palavras ao invés de buscar uma a uma no banco de dados buscar todas da frase separadas por aliases que são as próprias palavras da busca.

O mais perto que cheguei foi o primeiro exemplo.

Comment: Você já tentou fazer? Coloque seu código `PHP` na pergunta

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como Fazer dois ou mais Select categorizados na mesma consulta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239848/como-fazer-dois-ou-mais-select-categorizados-na-mesma-consulta)